# Avoid that JDialog adding Comp more then 1 Time?

Tags: java, singleton, menuitem, jdialog

I have created a Singleton that extends from JDialog. I do that because I want to avoid that a User can't create as many as they want. I just want one. Now I know the Singleton is the problem.

> **Is there a better way without Singleton maybe with an example it would be great. Because I must do that for other MenuItem as well.**

[Open the MenuItem First Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAx4I.png)

[Open the MenuItem Second Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuAhs.png)

This is my Method which starts if the MenuItem is clicked.

```
JButton confirmBTN = new JButton("Confirm");
    addComp(panel, confirmBTN, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);

    JButton closeBTN = new JButton("close");
    addComp(panel, closeBTN, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);


    this.dialog.setTitle("show Manual");
    this.dialog.setSize(200, 200);
    this.dialog.setVisible(true);
    this.dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);




    dialog.add(panel);
    dialog.pack();
```

That my Singleton

```
public class SingletonJDialog extends JDialog {
private static SingletonJDialog dialog;

private SingletonJDialog() {

}

public static SingletonJDialog getInstace() {

    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new SingletonJDialog();
    }
    return dialog;
}
}
```

That's how I get my instance.

```
private SingletonJDialog dialog = SingletonJDialog.getInstace();
```

Comment: If you're going to use a singleton, then you should be managing them through a `enum`

Comment: So, the problem isn't with your singleton, it's with the fact that each time the `ActionListener` is triggered, it adds more components to the dialog. Overall, I have no idea why you think you need this setup. There's nothing stopping a user from making their own dialog from scratch.

Comment: also show the whole code and not just fragments

Comment: Thats the whole code I forgot just the method head. MadProgrammer you are right. Thats my problem. I searching for way to avoid that the action listener called many times